# What is the fastest way to access huge XMLs in salami slice format?

Tags: xml, xslt, streaming

Everyday we get latest XMLs which contain the complete set of data. This can happen even multiple times in a single day. Now we would like to run our test scripts which accesses this data in XMLs. The XML is structured in Salami Slice format.

```
<Book id="01">
    <Name>A</Name>
    <ChapterRef id="02"></ChapterRef>
</Book>

<Book id="03" >
    <Name>B</Name>
    <ChapterRef ref="02"></ChapterRef>
    <ChapterRef ref="04"></ChapterRef>
</Book>

<Chapter id="02">
    <Name>Introduction</Name>
    <nPages>10</nPages>
</Chapter>

<Chapter id="04">
    <Name>Summary</Name>
    <nPages>20</nPages>
</Chapter>
```

**Note:** ids are unique.

Using Xpath/XQuery, the query to access data is like :- Get value of **nPages** where Book.Name = "B" && Chapter.Name = "Summary".

**Issue:**
There is huge amount of data in XMLs. Therefore, random access to these XML files as shown above takes lot of time. Currently we are using XSLT to transform the data from salami slice to russian doll to make the access to the data fast. But this makes the XML file very large.

I wanted to know if native XML based databases (BaseX etc.)can help in this regard or not. Can they store data in salami slice format (without transformation) with indexing so as to have fast data access?
Also one important factor to consider is that if importing of this data to native XML based databases, and its indexing takes a lot of time or is a manual task then also this solution is not a viable solution.

**Note:** Only "Read Only" random access is required to read data in database. There is no need to write it back into XMLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing large XML documents with XSLT is possible using streaming, which is also a way to force yourself to go only once through the document. Streaming is also designed to work "as the data arrives", which means that the transformation can already start while another process is writing the stream (can be a file or a stream of bytes, as long as it is XML).

This is a new feature of XSLT 3.0 and supported (at least) by [Saxon](http://saxonica.com) and [Exselt](http://exselt.net).

If you need random access, an XML database is probably a better solution. You can use XQuery to do updates of only the parts that need updating, preventing you to have to deal with a huge initial set of XML each time. Also, with XQuery, you can re-use your existing skills with XSLT + XPath, as the languages have a lot in common, but XQuery is more geared towards database access.

StackOverflow does not allow recommendations of tools, so I won't go into which of the many XML databases you should choose, which obviously will be a decision based on budget, implementation time, reuse of existing technology and knowledge etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about steaming feature in XSLT 3.0. I'll try it out.